# Git: add not staging files

Tags: git

I made changes to a file. After attempting to stage the file with `git add` (like always) I went on to commit `git commit -m`. However, the terminal spit this out at me:

```
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

I checked `git status` :

```
#On branch master
#Changes not staged for commit:
#(use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#(use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory) modified:   ../../Round 1/R1C3/R1C3.py
```

After some searching around on the tubes I discovered that I could stage the file in various other ways, but not with `git add` without flags. I could use either `git add -A` or `git add -u` or stage using interactive staging.

Baffled and not really understanding why my reg `git add` wasn't working, I forged on using `git add -A`. The story gets weird. After a restart on my machine (2011 Macbook Air running Mavericks) I tried good ol' `git add` again on the same file after some changes...and guess what? IT WORKED. So I continued on.

Now, a short time later, I have the same problem again. `git add` will not work (same directory).

Does anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong? It isn't a really big problem, because of the aforementioned alternatives, but I would like to understand why this is happening. Especially because this has always worked for me in the past, and now today, it broke :(

**NOTE: My other version controlled projects on my computer don't seem to be affected.

```
git add R1C3.py
git status
#On branch master
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   modified:   ../../Round 1/R1C3/R1C3.py
# no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")

git add -A
git status
# On branch master
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#   modified:   ../../Round 1/R1C3/R1C3.py
#
```

Comment: FYI, I *never* use `git add` alone. I didn't know that was possible. And; I've never had a problem.

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep that in mind as I move forward.

Answer (score 24):

When you do a `git add` it should be run in the same directory as the file or passed a relative path to the file. Since the file is located in the parent directory, `git add` will not find the file. In your case, you should `cd ../../Round 1/R1C3/` and then run `git add R1C3.py`.

`git add -A`, works because it stages all files in your repository, disregarding where you are in the directory.

Comment: My current directory is `Round 1/R1C3/`. No dice. Same thing happens. Thanks for looking.

Comment: I am having same issue although in the right directory and I am using git add . to add all files that have been modified.  I am in correct directory and correct branch

Comment: @cd491415 - How did you fixed it? :)

Comment: I havent but I suspect that the remote is having some line ending corrupted, so we are thinkiing to start using .gitattributes instead of using gits autocrlf setting.  But no fix so far.