# git add of unstaged file succeeds, but file is not staged

Tags: git

I have a number of files that I noticed are not in my repo.  One of those files is:

```
> ls -l emtProblemSet1Problem1.tex
  682  -rw-r--r--  1 pjoot  staff  3605  6 Oct 10:00 emtProblemSet1Problem1.tex
```

Git seems to think that the file isn't in the repo (although I am sure that I would have 'git add'ed it sometime prior to this) :

```
> git rm -n emtProblemSet1Problem1.tex
fatal: pathspec 'emtProblemSet1Problem1.tex' did not match any files
```

I can add it explicitly:

```
> git add emtProblemSet1Problem1.tex
> echo $?
0
```

but then commit doesn't think that it's been added:

```
> git commit emtProblemSet1Problem1.tex
error: pathspec 'emtProblemSet1Problem1.tex' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

commit -a is acting no differently.

I've checked that the file in question was not in .gitignore.  I'm running on mac, not cygwin, so don't have a file name case issue.

I'm not sure what else could explain this, and don't get any errors when I attempt to do the git add, and [am running it from the same directory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21358419/189270).  I [do have some submodules in my git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38837333/git-add-not-adding-files-in-specific-subdirectory), but this directory is not one of them.

EDIT: I was able to hack around this issue, by moving the files to a new directory (../tmp/), adding them in that directory, and then git mv'ing them back to the place I wanted.  I am able to 'touch foo ; git add foo ; git commit foo' and this works fine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a filesystem case insensitivity issue.  I'd thought that the Mac filesystem was case sensitive, but that no longer appears to be the case.

```
$ rm -f t T
$ echo hi > t
$ cat T
hi
```

It appears that I've got 'git' thinking that the file exists in a different case than it appears in 'ls', and modifications to that alternate case are showing up as unstaged.

I've been able to remove the two versions of the file by running:

```
git mv emtproblemSet1Problem1.tex Set1Problem1.tex
```

which results in two actions to be commited:

```
renamed:    emtproblemSet1Problem1.tex -> Set1Problem1.tex
deleted:    emtProblemSet1Problem1.tex
```